# How to use Google mirror for Maven Central as a direct link to download an artifact/jar?

Tags: maven, maven-mirroring

I am using a shell script to download a number of jar files from maven central repo using direct links (e.g. - [this link](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/openapitools/openapistylevalidator/openapi-style-validator-cli/1.3/openapi-style-validator-cli-1.3-all.jar)). I read on a couple of sources that Google hosts a publicly available copy of all the Maven Central artifacts and using it instead of Maven Central provides significant speed up in terms of download speed.

However, to achieve this I could only find out the Maven settings.xml references for using Google mirror (like below):

```
<settings>
  <mirrors>
    <mirror>
      <id>google-maven-central</id>
      <name>GCS Maven Central mirror Asia Pacific</name>
      <url>https://maven-central-asia.storage-download.googleapis.com/maven2/</url>
      <mirrorOf>central</mirrorOf>
    </mirror>
  </mirrors>
</settings>
```

But this doesn't solve my purpose. I am looking for direct download links to be used in a shell script and not in a maven project. How to do that?

Comment: Can you explain why you use a script to download artifacts and not Maven itself? Which Maven version do you use?

Comment: @khmarbaise I am creating a Docker utility which can be used to do OpenAPI Specification standard validation for which I am using the 'openapi-style-verification' tool. To build my utility, I only need the jar and do not want to have a maven project to get the same. Thats why, I am downloading it via a shell script which runs as a part of my docker build and places this jar in my docker image to be used further by the docker container.

Comment: Can be done easily via Maven while giving the dependencies and placing them into a directory which can be picked up to the container...

Comment: It is easier to curl a link to the jar.

Comment: In the pom file you simply define the GAV for all of your artifacts and they will be downloaded automatically. If we are talking about more than 3-4 artifacts...but of course it's up to you..

Comment: You saved my life, I am working on a project and the maven dependency removed from maven central today !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer to my question. It was easy, you just need to replace the host in the complete URL of the artifact/jar from maven central to google mirror. The structure of the URL looks like:

```
<HOST><Path to artifact>
```

Host can assume values of either the maven central repo host or of any mirror for the maven repo.

Example:

- If downloading from Maven Central, use:

https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/openapitools/openapistylevalidator/openapi-style-validator-cli/1.3/openapi-style-validator-cli-1.3-all.jar

- If downloading from Asia Pacific Google Mirror of Maven Central, use:

https://maven-central-asia.storage-download.googleapis.com/maven2/org/openapitools/openapistylevalidator/openapi-style-validator-cli/1.3/openapi-style-validator-cli-1.3-all.jar

- If downloading from EU region Google Mirror of Maven Central, use:

https://maven-central-eu.storage-download.googleapis.com/maven2/org/openapitools/openapistylevalidator/openapi-style-validator-cli/1.3/openapi-style-validator-cli-1.3-all.jar

- If downloading from Americas region Google Mirror of Maven Central, use:

https://maven-central.storage-download.googleapis.com/maven2/org/openapitools/openapistylevalidator/openapi-style-validator-cli/1.3/openapi-style-validator-cli-1.3-all.jar

Comment: As I commented on the question, you saved my life ! thank you.